# AES encryption between python and Node.js with PKCS7Padding

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, encryption, cryptography

I am trying with no success to decrypt a message with pkcs7 padding in Node.js. This message was encrypted and sent from Python code. I managed make it work in pure Python but can't figure out how to implement the decode (pkcs7 padding) functionality in Node.js. Can anybody help me reproduce the code?

Python Encode-Encrypt

```
import base64
import hashlib
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import pkcs7

text = "data"
pasword = "key"    

pw_bytes = pasword.encode('utf-8')
text_bytes = text.encode('utf-8')

m = hashlib.md5()
m.update(pw_bytes)
key = m.hexdigest()
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
pad_text = pkcs7.encode(text_bytes)
msg = cipher.encrypt(pad_text)
EncodeMsg = base64.b64encode(msg)
encryptedstring = EncodeMsg.decode("utf-8")
print(encryptedstring)

# Output: SxQE+SERkAzYcdG/ESAhiQ==
```

In addition, I put custom code for pkcs7 padding in Python **pkcs7.py**

```
import binascii
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO


def decode(bytestring, k=16):
    val = binascii.hexlify(bytestring[-1])
    val = int(val, 16)
    if val > k:
        raise ValueError('Input is not padded or padding is corrupt')
    l = len(bytestring) - val
    return bytestring[:l]


def encode(bytestring, k=16):
    l = len(bytestring)
    output = StringIO()
    val = k - (l % k)
    for _ in range(val):
        output.write('%02x' % val)
    return bytestring + binascii.unhexlify(output.getvalue())
```

Node.js Decrypt

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-128-ecb', 'key');
var decrypted = decipher.update('SxQE+SERkAzYcdG/ESAhiQ==', 'base64', 'utf8');
decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');

console.log(decrypted);
```

This is the error:

```
Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
    at Error (native)
    at Decipher.Cipher.final (crypto.js:153:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/Documents/Testing-Repo/node.js/testing.js:21:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Timeout.Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:447:10)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:224:11)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:198:5)
```

Comment: Please tell me that you are using ECB for exposition rather than because your real system is going to use ECB.

Comment: As you can see yes i use ECB cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)

Comment: ECB mode is not very secure, you need a very good and informed reason to use it, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29) (scroll down to the penguin image) for why.

Comment: i know you are right but that is not my problem right now. I will use AES.MODE_CBC with Iv(parameters) when my problem fixed.Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replacing `key = m.hexdigest()` with `key = m.digest()` should solve your problem.

Comment: Replacing key = m.hexdigest() with key = m.digest()  solved my problem thats only not ,the other one you can dlete it.I loveee you

Comment: @xXxpRoGrAmmErxXx Please keep your question as clean as possible so that people who read this question later can find it useful. I understand your problem is solved just by replacing hexdigest() with digest(), however putting wrong code to the question may cause confusion to others.

Comment: I edited the code in the question and removed the part from this answer.